# passing data, still nil in the other ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have two ViewController in A I try to pass a User object in the B V.C but it is still nil :

IN A :

```
User * user = (self.users)[indexPath.row];


UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

CVUserDetailsViewController *userVC = (CVUserDetailsViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CVUserViewController"];

userVC.selectedUser = [[User alloc] init];
userVC.selectedUser = user;



-> breakpoint [self.navigationController pushViewController:userVC animated:YES];
```

At the breakpoint, the user object "selectedUser" is not nil and contains data.

But here when B is loaded :

```
//Instanciate a new header profile from CVUserHeaderView
    _header = [[CVUserHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 63, self.view.frame.size.width, 160)];
    _header.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

//Add the attributes
_header.trigram = _selectedUser.trigram;
_header.title_job = _selectedUser.title_job;
_header.main_skills = @"IOS, Android";
  --->breakpoint 2  _header.mission_state = _selectedUser.mission_state;
```

My _selectedUser object is nil, what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Show how you're declaring the selectedUser property on B. Make a dealloc method on User and set a breakpoint... My suspicion is that your object is getting destroyed when you think it's being retained.

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) User * selectedUser;

Comment: Where I should make a dealloc?

Comment: Put the dealloc on your user object. Just nslog it. Breakpoint it and see if it gets called. That will confirm (or deny) the hypothesis.

Comment: What is `selectedObject`?  Why are you setting `userVC.selectedUser` to two different objects on consecutive lines?

Comment: yes it is deallocate

Comment: because I need to alloc my object in the V.C B before to set his data

Comment: there is no selectedObject sorry I correct that

Comment: You don't need to alloc an object when the next thing you do is replace it with a different one.

Comment: Oh ok but it is still nil

Comment: Any difference if you use `self.selectedUser` instead of `_selectedUser`?

Comment: there is no difference

Comment: I'm now getting suspicious that you have more than one `CVUserDetailsViewController`.  Try `NSLog(@"Sending to %@", userVC);` after you assign `user` and `NSLog(@"Checking in %@", self);` where you have breakpoint 2.  Do they print the same object addresses?  Does "sending" print before "checking"?

Comment: they are different..

Sending to <CVUserDetailsViewController: 0x7c077710>
2015-06-11 08:36:19.143 cvteque[39300:6450733] Checking in <CVUserDetailsViewController: 0x7bf56890>
2015-06-11 08:36:22.162 cvteque[39300:6450733]

Comment: I saw that my viewcontroller is loaded twice.